# Crear lista de dicconario desde iteracion en ciclo for

Tags: python, diccionarios

Vengo con mi segunda pregunta, apenas estoy iniciando en la programación en python.

Al grano:

Estoy iterando sobre los datos de una lista de diccionarios, y necesito crear otra lista de diccionarios con ciertos datos que yo selecciono. La lista nueva ya la tengo creada vacía, los diccionarios quiero que se agreguen por cada iteración.

Este el la idea del codigo:

```
lista_dict_vacia = []   

lista_dict_actual = [{'dato1': 'valor1'}, {'dato2': 'valor2'},      
 {'dato3': 'valor3'}, {'dato4': 'valor4'}]

for item in lista_dict_actual:

      if item['dato1'] == item['dato4']:
         enviar el item['dato1'] con su valor a lista_dict_vacia
         enviar el item['dato4'] con su valor a lista_dict_vacia 

De modo que la nueva lista de diccionaios quede así:

lista_dict_vacia = [{'dato1': 'valor1','dato4': 'valor4'}]
```

Me di a entender? Cualquier ayuda se los agredezco un millon!

Comment: Por que siempre se come la primera parte de la pregunta? Se suponía que debía decir "Buenas tardes, vengo con mi segunda pregunta..."

Comment: Hola, David, los saludos se eliminan automáticamente, mírate a pubicación en Meta [Los saludos en castellano ya se eliminan automáticamente de los encabezados de las publicaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3149/los-saludos-en-castellano-ya-se-eliminan-autom%c3%a1ticamente-de-los-encabezados-de-l). Otra cosa, veo que te estás peleando con el formato de código... :) Para formatear el código solo tienes que copiarlo, pegarlo, seleccionar el código recién pegado y pulsar `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor..

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, en principio basta con que en el `if` uses `lista_dict_vacia.append(item)` o directamente crear la lista usando list comprehension, `lista_dict_vacia  = [item for item in lista_dict_actual if condición]`. el built-in`filter` también sería una opción.  Es un poco genérica la pregunta, si no te aclaras agrega un ejemplo real, con una condición real para poder afinar más.

Comment: Chevere, entiendo lo de los saludos. En cuanto a la pregunta, la corregí. Lo que necesito es que si los item['dato'] son iguales, esos dos datos ('dato1': 'valor1','dato4': 'valor4')  entren a la lista de diccionarios, como un diccionario. Por cada iteracion se creara entonces la lista de diccionarios.

Comment: En este caso, cada valor es único. Estoy iterando sobre códigos numéricos. Ya existe una validación anterior, donde si el valor numerico ya existe, no pasa por esta iteracion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Señores, ya di con la solución, lo que hice fue que por cada iteración sobre la primera lista de diccionarios, guardé el valor de la clave en una variable. Despues apliqué la condición a esas variables que ya contenían el valor de las claves.   **Si la condicion se cumple, se crea un diccionario llamado 'data', donde yo defino el nombre de la clave, y el valor de éstas son las variables que cumplieron la condición**. Después que termina la iteración sobre el dato, introduzco ese diccionario en la lista vacía antes definida. 
Siguiendo el código de mi pregunta, quedó exactamente Así:

`lista_dict_vacia = []
 lista_dict_actual = [{'dato1': 'valor1'}, 
                      {'dato2': 'valor2'},
                      {'dato3': 'valor3'}, 
                      {'dato4': 'valor4'}
                     ] 
for item in lista_dict_actual:
    variable1 = item['dato1']
    variable2 = item['dato4']
    if variable1 == variable2:
       data = {'clave1': variable1,
               'clave2': variable2
              } 
lista_dict_vacia.append(data)
lista_dict_vacia = [{'clave1': variable1, 
                          'clave2': variable2}]`